# how to activate kite in pycharm?

Tags: pycharm, kite

I have downloaded the exe file,install it, verify my email, but i not work in my pycharm, I can't find any solutions by google. and the offical website of kite has no specific tutorial about this. thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the .dmg file and open it. It will ask you for which programs you'd like to activate Kite. Select PyCharm and you're gtg.

Comment: but i can only find the .exe file in the website in kite, can you send a download link to me, my pycharm is a edu version in windows 10. the developer told me that there are some issues for kite to find my installation directory. and they are solving it now

Comment: Have you able to install Kite? Just run the exe file and follow the installation steps. Then restart pycharm.

Comment: i have install it ,and in "http://localhost:46624/settings/plugins" ,it shows that kite has installed pycharm plugins. although i have restarted my pycharm, i can not see anything about kite in my pycharm

Comment: @DeanWang just start a python code or file and wait some minutes for Kite to index your code. It should work after that

Answer (score 4):

If you have pyCharm and python latest version Then open your PyCharm IDE  And head over to settings >plugins search for Kite then Install It.

Now you're good to gO

Answer (score 1):

You need to ADD the directory which your Python codes are reside (permissions) in Kite Local Settings i.e.:
T:\Python_Data. Added to the WHITELISTED DIRECTORIES

Kite settings can be invoke by mouse click on Kite symbol (right corner of the editor).